# FlashCS6 - Actionscript 3 - Loading SWFs - All playing but one

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm just playing around trying to get a navigation bar to work and I'm having a spot of trouble. I've got a `main.swf`, and inside it is code to load in a `circle.swf`, `square.swf` and `triangle.swf` on their respective button clicks. The circle and square load in and play correctly, however the triangle loads, but doesn't play for some reason. The code, to my eye, is the same for all three, but only that one doesn't play.

Note sure where exactly the bug might be, but below it the code referring to the specific swfs. Let me know if it's helpful to see more though.

```
var _swfPathArr:Array = new Array("Subfolder/Circle.swf", "Subfolder/Subsubfolder/Square.swf", "Triangle.swf");
```

and

```
button_Circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
button_Square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
button_Triangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
```

And the method actually displaying and clearing the loaded swfs:

```
function setContent(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var _swfToAdd:MovieClip;

    switch(event.target.name)
    {
        case "button_Circle":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[0];
        gotoAndStop(2);
        break;

        case "button_Square":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[1];
        gotoAndStop(3);
        break;

        case "button_Triangle":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[2];
        gotoAndStop(4);
        break;
    }

    Window_content.removeChildAt(Window_content.numChildren - 1);
    Window_content.addChild(_swfToAdd);
}
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
All the code

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var _swfLoader:Loader;
var _swfRequest:URLRequest;

var _swfPathArr:Array = new Array("Subfolder/Circle.swf", "Subfolder/Subsubfolder/Square.swf", "Triangle.swf");
var _loadedSWFs:int;

var _swfClipsArr:Array = new Array();
var _swfTempClip:MovieClip;

startLoading(_swfPathArr);

function startLoading(pathArr:Array):void
{
    _swfLoader = new Loader();
    _swfRequest = new URLRequest();

    addChildAt(_swfLoader, 0);

    _loadedSWFs = 0;

    loadSWF(pathArr[0]);

}

function loadSWF(path:String):void
{
    setUpListeners(_swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo);

    _swfRequest.url = path;
    _swfLoader.load(_swfRequest);

}

function setUpListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void
{
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfComplete);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, currentSwfProgress);

}

function currentSwfProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var _perc:int = (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) * 100;
    //swfPreloader.precentTF.text = _perc + "%";
}

function onSwfComplete(event:Event):void
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfComplete);
    event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, currentSwfProgress);

    _swfTempClip = event.target.content;
    _swfTempClip.customID = _loadedSWFs;

    _swfClipsArr.push(_swfTempClip);

    if(_loadedSWFs < (_swfPathArr.length - 1))
    {
        _loadedSWFs++;
        loadSWF(_swfPathArr[_loadedSWFs]);
    }
    else
    {
        _swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
        _swfLoader = null;
        onCompletePreloading();
    }

}

function onCompletePreloading():void
{
    button_Circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
    button_Square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
    button_Triangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
}

function setContent(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var _swfToAdd:MovieClip;

    switch(event.target.name)
    {
        case "button_Circle":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[0];
        gotoAndStop(2);
        break;

        case "button_Square":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[1];
        gotoAndStop(3);
        break;

        case "button_Triangle":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[2];
        gotoAndStop(4);
        break;
    }

    Window_content.removeChildAt(Window_content.numChildren - 1);
    Window_content.addChild(_swfToAdd);
    //trace(_swfToAdd.customID);
}

stop();
```

So thanks to Cherniv suggesting to switch the order of the SWFs and see what happens, it seems the problem is related to the third element in the path array. Just need a pair of outside eyes to look over the code and they'll probably be able to spot some very obvious reason for my trouble, haha. If anybody can spot it, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: and what happened if you switch the order in `_swfPathArr` ?

Comment: for what are the 'gotoAndStop()' methods? Also if the swf loads and doesnt play. the problem isnt in the loader but most likly in the loaded swf!

Comment: I don't know Cherniv, I'll look into that when I get into the lab tomorrow.

Comment: The gotoAndStop() methods just take the stage to a frame where the clicked on button is larger in size, to show which button's swf is playing, the code doesn't actually change any. That's what I thought M4tchB0X3r, but just opening that swf by itself, it plays normally.

Comment: what does your Loader function look like? Are u usung Loader or ProLoader?

Comment: I'm using a Loader. I can upload the rest of the code tomorrow once I get into the lab if that helps.

Comment: Sorry it took me an extra day to upload the rest of the code M4tchB0X3r

Comment: Oh, and Cherniv, if I switch Circle.swf with the Triangle.swf, Triangle loads and plays, but Circle now only loads, it doesn't play. So the problem must be related to the third element in the array.